# How to form an equation for probability based on the following graph?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random

[image]

The y-axis is the probability density function of x( a continuous random variable).

Here's the solution I tried:
[image: formula]

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You could also just calculate the area of the triangle (that is what the integral does) and say it is equal to 1.

$$ \dfrac{(8*k)}{2 }= 4k = 1 => k = \dfrac{1}{4} $$

For problems with more complicated functions, to use the integral is your only option.

Comment: thank you. am i also right to assume that the total probability over the area on the interval [-4,4] is equal to 1 because if you integrate a PDF from negative infinity to positive infinity it should equal 1?

Comment: Yes.  The integral from negative infinity to positive infinity is equal to the integral from -4 to 4, since PDF(x) = 0 for x ∉ ]-4, 4[. That's why we can say the integral from 4 to -4 is equal to 1.